# haskell set data type

Tags: haskell

hey everyone I am trying to figure out how to make a set data type in haskell, but I cannot figure this out, this is what i have so far, i am a bit confused

```
data Set a = Node a | List {
    list :: [a]
}deriving(Eq,Show,Ord)

insert :: Set Integer -> Set Integer -> Bool
insert (Node itemToInsert) (List list)
    |contains (List list) (Node itemToInsert) == False = List(list:(Node itemToInsert))


contains :: Set Integer -> Set Integer -> Bool
contains (List []) (Node numberToFind) = False
contains (List (x:xs)) (Node numberToFind)
    |x == (Node numberToFind) = True
    |otherwise = contains (List (xs)) (Node numberToFind)
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: I want a list of Nodes and I cannot figure out how define the data type to do that.

Comment: You can't specify "this is a list of a particular constructor": use smart constructors for something like that, or use another data type.  But why are you trying to define a new Set data type, when we have Data.Set?  And if you're wanting to represent a graph (hinted at by "Node"), then either say so or use an existing graph library!

Comment: Why was this voted down? Seems like an honest question

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From your code it seems you have already understood, that a set can be seen as a list without duplicates. So let us express this in a simple type definition:

```
data Set a = Set [a]
```

In order to ensure that there are no duplicates, one can introduce 'smart constructors' which are functions that aren't  technically a constructor, but which are used as such.

```
empty :: Set a
empty = Set []
```

We'll need another one to create non-empty sets. Let's have a look at your `insert` function. Why does it return a `Bool`? Shouldn't it return a set? Why does `insert` expect two sets? So to insert an integer into a set of integers one could you use the following type signature:

```
insert :: Integer -> Set Integer -> Set Integer
```

The implementation consists of two cases: 1. the given integer is not in the given set, and 2. the given integer is in the given set.

```
insert x (Set xs)
    | not (x `elem` xs) = Set (x:xs)
    | otherwise         = Set xs
```

Since, this question seems to be part of a homework assignment. I'd say you should try to figure out how to implement `elem` yourself.